# How to display multiple EAGLView from one screen of iPhone/iPad?

Tags: ios, ios4, opengl-es-2.0

Just like the effects of "Photo Booth" application in macosx.

Is that possible to display 4 EAGLViews at same time ?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to render to the same EAGLView using glViewport. You can then render in part of the backbuffer without changing anything.

glViewport (http://www.khronos.org/opengles/documentation/opengles1_0/html/glViewport.html) takes the lowerleft corner position and the size of the rectangle.